# Swipe Back Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

```
import UIKit

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning",
               message: "Your number is too big.",
               preferredStyle: .alert)

  
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
          
    // Verbindungen zu Storyboard
 
    @IBAction func rechnerEntry(_ sender: Any) {
    }
     
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
     
    @IBOutlet weak var buttons: UIButton!
     
    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: Any) {
       
      calculatorLabel.text = ""
      number = 0
    }
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
     
      buttons.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }
     
    // Aufführung happyFuncs
     
    func happyFunc(number: Int) -> Int {
       
      var myNum = number
      var sum = 0
      while myNum > 0 {
        let x = myNum % 10
        sum += (x * x)
        myNum /= 10
      }
      return sum
    }
     
    // happyCheckerFunc
     
    func happyChecker(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
      var alreadychecked: Set<Int> = Set()
      var result = happyFunc(number: x)
     
      while !alreadychecked.contains(result) {
         
        if result == 1 {
          resultLabel.text = "your number is a happy number"
          return true
        }
         
        alreadychecked.insert(result)
        result = happyFunc(number: result)
      }
      resultLabel.text = "your number is a unhappy number"
      return false
    }
     
    // Eingabe Werte
     
    var number = 0
    var x = 0
     
    @IBOutlet weak var calculatorLabel: UILabel!
     
    var isTypingNumber = false
     
    // Nummer getippt
     
    @IBAction func numberTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
      let number = sender.currentTitle ?? (sender.titleLabel?.text ?? "0")
       
      if isTypingNumber {
        calculatorLabel.text = calculatorLabel.text! + number
      } else {
        calculatorLabel.text = number
        isTypingNumber = true
      }
       
    }
   
    // Überprüfung happy?
     
    @IBAction func happycheck(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
      number = Int(calculatorLabel.text!)!
       
      x = number
       
      if x > 9999999999999999 {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                       style: .default,
                       handler: { _ in
           print("OK tap")
        }))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
         
      }
      func happyFunc(number: Int) -> Int {
         
        var myNum = number
        var sum = 0
        while myNum > 0 {
          let x = myNum % 10
          sum += (x * x)
          myNum /= 10
        }
        return sum
      }
      
      func happyChecker(_ x: Int) -> Bool {
        var alreadychecked: Set<Int> = Set()
        var result = happyFunc(number: x)
         
        while !alreadychecked.contains(result) {
           
          if result == 1 {
            resultLabel.text = "your number is a happy number"
            return true
          }
           
          alreadychecked.insert(result)
          result = happyFunc(number: result)
        }
        resultLabel.text = "your number is a unhappy number"
        return false
      }
       
      happyChecker(x)
    }
  
  }
```

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmN6k.png)

Hey I wanted to ask you how I can implement the Swipe back Gesture in Swift. So I want that the user start at the Home View Controller and then he can tap on the "happy number Rechner"-Button and then the calculator View Controller appears. Like the same way with the transitions in the Settings App of iOS. And if you swipe left the Home View should appear again. Thank you!

Comment: Use a navigation controller. If you push the next controller onto the navigation controller you automatically get the swipe feature.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need `NavigationController, and ViewController`
You can find and add this such like when you add a button.
After that click your Button, hold on the option button your keyboard, and pull together the first-and secondviewcontroller, now add you a navigationcontroller( you will see 2 screen, just delete a tableview controller screen) and don't forget to put a new way your arrow.(nav.controller first)